# Form function is not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to execute function on change within form.

```
<ul class="list booking-filters-list">
  <li>
     <h5 class="booking-filters-title">Price</h5>
      <input type="text" id="price-slider">
  </li>
  <li>                                    
    <h5 class="booking-filters-title">Star Rating</h5>
    <form id="hotelRating" name="hotelRating" onchange="filterBy()">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input class="i-check" type="checkbox" name="5" value="5.0" />5 star</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input class="i-check" type="checkbox" name="4" value="4.0" />4 star</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input class="i-check" type="checkbox" name="3" value="3.0" />3 star</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input class="i-check" type="checkbox" name="2" value="2.0" />2 star</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input class="i-check" type="checkbox" name="1" value="1.0" />1 star</label>
    </div>
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Script funciton:

```
<script>
  function filterBy() { 
  $('.searchtable').addClass('hide');
  $('.spinner').removeClass('hide');

  $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {'name':'<?php echo strval($_GET['name']); ?>','arrival':'<?php echo strval($_GET['arrival']); ?>','departure':'<?php echo strval($_GET['departure']);?>','guests':'<?php echo strval($_GET['guests']);?>','propertyCategory':$("#hotelType input[type='checkbox']:checked").val(),'minStarRating':$("#hotelRating input[type='checkbox']:checked").val(),'order_by':$('#order_by').val()},
        url: '<?php echo $baseUrl ?>/hotels/hotelFilterResult.php',


        success: function (data) {
            alert('data loaded succesfully');
            alert(this.url);

            $('.searchtable').replaceWith(data);
            $('.spinner').addClass('hide');
            $('.searchtable').removeClass('hide');

        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('data not loaded');
        }
 });

 }
</script>
```

I have set the function filterBy() to execute onchange wihtin the form - but nothing is happening when I set one of the checkboxes.

EDIT: If I remove the class "i-check" the function is called. Why can that be ?

Can any spot what I do wrong ?

Comment: Is your call successful? What is your console saying when the function executes?

Comment: Generally you put an `onchange` onto a changeable element (eg the actual checkbox), I'm not sure it's supposed to work on the whole form.

Comment: BTW, you probably have a reflected XSS vulnerability in the places you echo the `$_GET` variables. @TarynEast `change` events should bubble.

Comment: Add something like this before you output and watch your console.  console.log("recieved data-------*\n\nResponse : " + response +"\n\nStatus : " + status); see if the data is even sending. Before your replaceWith. .HTML I always find more useful as you keep your container.

Comment: "The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements."

Comment: @j08691 "Bubbles Yes" - [MDN page on the change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change). ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fdgnhonc/)).

Comment: Also I think the event of checking a box is captured with onclick not onchange. You may need to change the way you are handling your events and attach a .click to your checkbox and on change to your inputs

Comment: If I remove the class "i-check" , the function works. Can't figure out why.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/7y7y460q/

Comment: I am not sure if it is your need But certainly you are trying to submit the star rating on change of any of check boxes. why to put change event on form instead of check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
           console.log("recieved data-------*\n\nResponse : " + response +"\n\nStatus : " + status);
```

$('.searchtable').replaceWith(data);

Add this console statement and open development tools for browser and watch console. I doubt it will be firing as a change will not be registered as you have added it to the form. You can add a class to you checkboxes like class = 'mycheckbox '

Then in jquery

```
$('.mycheckbox').click ...
```

Add document ready before.

Comment: If I remove the class "i-check" , the function works. Can't figure out why - @Creaven

Comment: Did you check console it might tell you why?